# Multi update on ledger using Putstate() in ChaincodeStub

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, smartcontracts

I have a scenario where i have to update multiple transactions in ledger at the same time.

In simple case, two transactions has to executed at the same time in order to make the use case valid. if anyone of them fails the other one should revert back.

```
err = stub.PutState(key, tradeJSONasBytes)
```

using hyperledger 1.1 and golang smart contract.

Comment: Fabric does not have a concept of reverting a transaction---after all, immutable ledger is at the base of it. Maybe your client can send the 2 tx-proposals and only when it receives both proposals successfully back, it can send them for ordering.

Comment: What you can do, is to probably implement the code in such a way that you use "deleteState" or "deletePrivateData" when something fails. This will basically hide the record, and when you query, wont be returned. However, it's still part of the ledger.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to save multiple transaction you can call multiple `PutState()` but there is nothing like reverting the transaction, even if the transaction fails it is still stored as a block, as it is the part of immutability condition.